# -bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long if there is a lot of PATH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-kernel, environment-variables

I have set about two thousand paths in PATH variable (I know its excessive but I experiment something) and whenever I try to run any command I get the following error, in this case its `ls`.

`-bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long`

I have checked several topics about the error message. However, I was wondering what does PATH var length have anything to do with arg list error.

Would anyone have an idea/explanation?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the `PATH` variable pushed the size of your environment over `ARG_MAX` on your system, or in the case of Linux, see https://psomas.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/arg_max-and-the-linux-kernel/.

Comment: The environment is essentially a second argument list, and is only interpreted as key/value pairs by convention. Linux calls it the [arg+env limit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b6a2fea39318e43fee84fa7b0b90d68bed92d2ba)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your posts, including the one below, makes more sense now. Diving into the link you provided.

Answer (score 4):

The same buffer is used to pass both command-line arguments and the environment to a new process. In this case, your value of `PATH` seems to be big enough for the environment to exceed whatever limit your OS places on the size of this buffer. Even a zero-argument list, therefore, is too long.